# UIColor colorWithPatternImage: fails on JPG file - but UIImage loads the JPG fine?

Tags: ios, uiimage

With files:

```
file1.JPG
file2.png
```

Loading a JPG as background fails:

```
(UITextfield).backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"file1"]];
```

Loading a PNG works:

```
(UITextfield).backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"file2"]];
```

Drag/dropping the JPG into an Interface Builder UIView works.

But init'ing a UIImageView fails:

```
[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:"file1"]];
```

Huh? This makes no sense to me :(. This is on iPad3 / iOS 5.1. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried using lowercase JPG in the file name?

Answer (score 1):

Self answering ... some bugs in Xcode to do with case sensitivity, combined with UIImage not supporting "jpg" as an automatic file extension.

1. Xcode treats "a.JPG" and "a.jpg" as the same file - even though they're not (Mac has case-sensitive filing system)
2. Xcode then crashes if you try to rename a file and change its case only. Ouch.

Further:

1. "file1" will ONLY check for ".png" (and @2x etc) ... not ".jpg" (oops, I'd forgotten that!)

Finally:

1. For some strange reason, my UIImageView isn't displaying any images at all any more. A separate problem with Interface Builder, I think :(